# How to retrieve data combination from both tables in one to one relationship in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two models that are `User` and `Patient`. The foreign key in Patient table is `user_id`.

User

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function patient()
    {
       return $this->hasOne(Patient::class);
    }
}
```

Patient

```
class Patient extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

When I ran this script, it doesn't retrieve both tables data

```
$patient_user = User::find($user->id)->patient;
```

Result

```
{
    "success": {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "ic": null,
        "gender": null,
        "age": null,
        "height": null,
        "weight": null,
        "allergy": null,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
    }
}
```

Expected result

```
{
    "success": {
        "name": "Mohammad",
        "email": "mohammadnrdn@gmail.com",
        "role": 1,
        "phone_number": null,
        "country_code": null,
        "authy_id": null,
        "verified": "0",
        "ic": null,
        "gender": null,
        "age": null,
        "height": null,
        "weight": null,
        "allergy": null,
        "created_at": "2018-08-28 07:42:16",
        "updated_at": "2018-08-28 07:42:16"
    }
}
```

Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `phone_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `authy_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `verified` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `patients` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ic` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `height` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `allergy` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: you mean to use `User::find($user->id)->load('patient')`?

Comment: yeah, yup2. thanks btw!!!

Comment: So this is an answer?

Comment: mostly yes. i can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Laravel, there is [Lazy eager-loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) of models, meaning a model's related models can be loaded after retrieving the model. Therefore, in your case you can you load patient:

```
User::find($user->id)->load('patient')
```

Otherwise you can [constrain eager-load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) the relation before retrieving the model:

```
User::with('patient')->find($user->id)
```